# Conditional statement for Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want my code to display a alert box if there are 0 adults and 0 children selected from the dropdowns.

I tried && but it didn't work

```
Adults: <select id="adults">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option selected value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>

    Child: <select id="childs">
        <option selected value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>

 <input type="Button" value="Submit" onClick="myFunction()">

 <script>

function myFunction() {

    var noadults = document.getElementById("adults").value;
    var nochilds = document.getElementById("childs").value;

    if (noadults && nochilds == 0)
        alert("Please select number of passengers.")

}           

</script>
```

Comment: Change your condition to `if (noadults ==0 && nochilds == 0)`.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition here:

```
  if (noadults && nochilds == 0)
```

Should be:

```
  if (noadults == 0 && nochilds == 0)
```